# LogisticRegression is expecting 17388 features as input

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying to create a model using Logistic Regression that will predict an endpoint. However, when running the last line of code shown below, I keep getting the error "X has 23146 features, but LogisticRegression is expecting 17388 features as input." I am aware that the features should match, but not sure how to fix the issue. I have applied some filtering and preprocessing of the X_train features, which is why they are not equal to the X_test.

both X_train and X_test are numpy arrays.

```
X_train= X_train.loc[:, (X_train != 0).any(axis=0)]
X_train = X_train.loc[:, (X_train==0).mean() < .25]

mm = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = mm.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = mm.fit_transform(X_test)

vt= VarianceThreshold(threshold=0.01)
X_train= vt.fit_transform(X_train)

lr = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs',max_iter=1000)

lr.fit(X_train, y_train) 

lr.score(X_train, y_train)

lr.score(X_test, y_test)
```

I have attempted solutions found online but none worked.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes  sorry im new to this. the added code is all the steps before. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `VarianceThreshold` was not applied on the test set. The estimator removes features, which explains why there were more features than expected at test time.

Usually: for each `fit_transform` on the training set, you also want to apply `transform` to the test set:

```py
mm = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = mm.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = mm.transform(X_test)

vt = VarianceThreshold(threshold=0.01)
X_train = vt.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = vt.transform(X_test)

lr = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs',max_iter=1000).(X_train, y_train)

lr.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Or simplify by writing steps in a `Pipeline`:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

pipe = make_pipeline(
    MinMaxScaler(),
    VarianceThreshold(threshold=0.01),
    LogisticRegression(solver="lbfgs"),
)

pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(f1_score(y_test, pipe.predict(X_test)))
```

Comment: Nice! If this resolved your problem, you can accept this answer. If the problem was caused by something else, you can add another answer!